# Do I need Transit Visa for Zurich (Expired stamped H1b, Valid I-797) travelling to India for stamping

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, visa-extensions, h1b-visas, zrh

I am an Indian Citizen currently working in USA on H1b visa. I will be travelling from Boston to New Delhi (India) via Zurich. Please help me out with information if I will need a transit visa to go via Zurich or not. I have a 1hr 45mins stopover in Zurich.

I have a valid Indian Passport but my currently stamped H1b visa is expired. I have a valid I-797 which I will use to get a H1b visa stamping in India. I have a confirmed round trip ticket to come back to Boston.

Please let me know if I need a Transit Visa in Zurich based on my situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need a visa in this case. In the Schengen area, most people can transit in international airports without a visa if they don't leave the transit area. This only works if you have only **one** layover in the Schengen area (so a BOS-FRA-ZRH-BOM route would **not** be OK because both FRA and ZRH are in the Schengen area).

However, even if you only have one layover, there are restrictions for the citizens of some countries (so-called annex IV countries). India is not one of them but individual Schengen member states can add other countries to that list and transit for Indian citizens is in fact [restricted in several member states](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf). Specifically, transiting in Germany, France, Spain and the Czech Republic is not possible for Indian citizens without an “airport transit visa”. You can still transit in Zurich because [Switzerland does not impose the same requirement](https://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/dam/data/bfm/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf).

Finally, a *valid* US visa would exempt you from the airport transit visa requirement where it applies but AFAIK the I-797 is not considered a valid document for visa-free transit.

Comment: perfect answer. went to india via zurich smoothly. no schengen visa required.